# How do you determine which validator failed?

Tags: asp.net, controls, validation

I am working with a page and I am getting an Page.IsValid = false and I am trying to determine which control is causing the validation problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In code (page_load), you can do this:
(per MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dh9ad08f%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

```
If (Me.IsPostBack) Then
    Me.Validate()
    If (Not Me.IsValid) Then
        Dim msg As String
        ' Loop through all validation controls to see which 
        ' generated the error(s).
        Dim oValidator As IValidator
        For Each oValidator In Validators
            If oValidator.IsValid = False Then
                msg = msg & "<br />" & oValidator.ErrorMessage
            End If
        Next
        Label1.Text = msg
    End If
End If
```

In the markup, you can...

- You can put "text" on your validator (like an
  asterisk...)
- Or use a validation_summary control (which requires an error message on your validator)...

Comment: Or `this.Validators.Where(v => !v.IsValid)` for short.

Comment: @Steven -- I keep meaning to learn about that -- very cool though -- you should get credit for that.

Comment: It is actually very easy to give me credits for that. Just click on the 'arrow up' simple on the left side of my comment ;-).

Comment: @Steven_ That doesn't compile because a `ValidatorCollection` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<IValidator>` but you could use `var v = Validators.Cast<IValidator>().Where(v => !v.IsValid);`

Answer (score 29):

Credit to [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264697/steven) for this answer, but I had to make some changes for it to work as this.Validators.Where() had some problems.

```
using System.Linq;

List<IValidator> errored = this.Validators.Cast<IValidator>().Where(v => !v.IsValid).ToList();
```

Comment: it didn't work the way @Steven said, but this answer is perfect. Only had to change the *this* for *Page*. thks

Comment: Instead of using this.Validators I am using Page.Validators

Comment: `Page.Validators` didn't work for me.. yes, somebody out there is still using WebForms... bleh. But this answer worked fine. Thanks +1

Comment: Building on this answer, I use the following code to identify the validator that is invalid:

    'if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        // do something
    }
    else
    {
 // page is not valid
 List<IValidator> invalides = this.Validators.Cast<IValidator>().Where(v => !v.IsValid).ToList();
 foreach (var invalid in invalides)
 {
  Debug.WriteLine(invalid.ErrorMessage);
 }
}'

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer allows you to find the validation *message* of the validator that failed.  If you want to find the *ID* of the control that failed validation, it is possible to get that by casting the validator to a [BaseValidator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator(v=vs.110).aspx) which exposes the `ControlToValidate` property.  For example:

```vb
For Each v As BaseValidator In Page.Validators
    If Not v.IsValid Then
        ' You can see the control to validate name and error message here.
        Debug.WriteLine(v.ControlToValidate)
        Debug.WriteLine(v.ErrorMessage)
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

To check which `Validator` is being fired, just check the HTML in Firebug and if any `Validator` is not having `display:none;` property or is having `visibility:visible` in its properties then it is the one which is causing `Page.IsValid` `false`.